# Trying to understand why two similar piece of code are different. First compiles well. Second does not

Tags: java

// compare 2 Strings

```
BinaryOperator<String> maxLengthString = BinaryOperator.maxBy(
            Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));
```

---

// compare 2 int

```
BinaryOperator<Integer> maxLengthString = BinaryOperator.maxBy(
            Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::compareTo));
```

Comment: Have a look at the messages you certainly get and also at the signature of the methods you're passing to  `comparingInt()`.

Comment: `String::length` takes one string and returns one int. `Integer::compareTo` takes **two** Integers and returns one int. That is not what `comparingInt` requires.

Comment: Seriously: **RTFM**. Look at the error and look at the method `length` vs. `compareTo`.

Comment: and so? I do not understand how the difference between these two methods affect the result

Answer (score 1):

**String::length** takes 1 String and returns 1 int.

**Integer::compareTo** takes 2 ints and returns 1 int.

Take a look at the methods' signature.

Answer (score 0):

The compareTo method expects implicitly an argument to be passed. In this context the compiler can't retrieve the argument, so it throws a compile time error.

Comment: But here the compiler can retrieve the argument?!
BinaryOperator<Integer> maxLengthString = BinaryOperator.maxBy(
                (Integer::compareTo));

What is the difference?